# VB.NET paste one image into another without losing quality

Tags: c#, vb.net, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to create VB.NET code for pasting a png image on center of another image. I am using the below code:

```
'create new image with watermark
Dim backImg = Image.FromFile("image path")
Dim mrkImg = Image.FromFile("watermark.png")
Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(backImg)
g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
Dim x = Convert.ToSingle((backImg.Width / 2) - (mrkImg.Width / 2))
Dim y = Convert.ToSingle((backImg.Height / 2) - (mrkImg.Height / 2))
g.DrawImage(mrkImg, x, y)
backImg.Save("result.jpg")
```

This is working, but i am noticing a decrease in quality :

[image]

(Blue one was the actual image, the red ones are part of png. Notice the edges.)

How can i do the same preserving the full quality? I had implemented the same functionality in python without losing any quality but not sure how to do in VB.NET

Comment: Chances are that the quality was what we see before.But you can try to save as png for a test and then improve the jpg quality by setting a lower compression.

Comment: Do you know how JPG compression works?

Answer (score -1):

The code below helps you:

```
 Using backImg As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test1.png"))

        Using mrkImg = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test2.png")
            Using final As Bitmap = New Bitmap(backImg.Width, backImg.Height)

                final.SetResolution(CSng(backImg.HorizontalResolution),
                                    CSng(backImg.VerticalResolution))

                Using g = Graphics.FromImage(final)

                    g.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                    g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                    g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

                    g.DrawImage(backImg, 0, 0)
                    g.DrawImage(mrkImg,
                                CSng((backImg.Width - mrkImg.Width) * 0.5),
                                CSng((backImg.Height - mrkImg.Height) * 0.5))
                End Using

                final.Save("C:\Users\User\Desktop\testResult.jpg")

            End Using

        End Using
End Using
```